# SQL Developer create a new user

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a new user in SQL Developer Oracle 12c database and when I try to create a new user:

```
CREATE USER usera IDENTIFIED BY mypsassword
```

I get this error:

> error starting at line 2 in command:
>   CREATE USER usera IDENTIFIED BY mypsassword
>
> Error at Command Line:2 Column:13
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name

What can I do?

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: The error message quite descriptive, did you try to check the syntax.

Comment: yeah nothing changed

Comment: i figured it out : you must put the prefix c## or C## before the name of the user for example C##pluto and its done

Answer (score 0):

Without specific knowledge of Oracle it seems to me that Oracle is nudging you to use less generic usernames. Try replacing `usera` with something else for example `pluto`.